How do implement stateful algorithms in 2PC using Garbled Circuits?
My assumptions: As far is I understood (correct me if I am wrong), Garbled Circuits Compilers transform a given function f(x_1, x_2) of interest into a network of gates and some form of evaluation framework then evaluates this for private inputs x_1 and x_2. These gate networks are then fixed, and as far as i understood can not be used as flip-flops to store a state. However, some algorithms require access to e.g. a stack such as a path-finding algorithm.
My problem: I am trying to implement a tree-search like algorithm with private inputs. I am planning to use GC for this.
My question for stackexchange: How exactly are then algorithms which require some form of mutable datastructure (e.g. a stack for a tree search algorithm) implemented in 2PC algorithms? If using garbled circuits then this obviously would not work as with those one (as far as i understood) can only implement combinatorial circuits.
In particular, I am looking for

a concrete example on how (where; in which project) this is done in any "GC compiler" with something that uses a mutable state e.g. a tree search
a theoretical explanation
and whether there are multiple different methods to do so.

I suspect the answer to this question involves using “ORAM”s and an “MPC Engine”. Firstly, am not sure if that is true. But if that is true, then i like an explanation about how these two components stand in relation to each other in enabling stateful computations.

The question states that "some algorithms require access to e.g. a stack such as a path-finding algorithm". That's correct. But there is not a single algorithm to solve a given problem. And as long as a problem instance (e.g. a graph) can be encoded as a finite number of bits, there exists a purely combinatorial circuit solving the problem and yielding the same result as any given deterministic algorithm. I'm not stating that's practical, or even feasible for real-size problems, must less that's how it's done. Thus I don't make this an answer.

Your question doesn't actually have anything to do with garbled circuits. You seem to simply be asking how a program in an unspecified computational model can be compiled into a Boolean circuit.

Would the question be answered by showing how to build a purely combinatorial circuit that, for fixed $\ell$ and $c$, given any maze of $\ell$ lines of $c$ boxes with start on $(0,0)$ and finish on ($\ell-1,c-1)$, defined by the $(\ell-1)(c-1)$ bits encoding the inner walls, outputs the length of the shortest path from start to finish?

I know that you can reformulate algorithms which use a stack also into algorithms which (although maybe cumbersome to formulate) do not use any internal state so just using a combinatorial circuits.
However, I am under the assumption that some 2PC problems are (in real-world) solved with stacks. I think my question is primarily: In what context are GC used, together with something that supplies some higher order logic to it (like an "MPC engine" or whatever this is) to solve algorithms implemented with stacks.

The question would not be answered by showing how to build a purely combinatorial circuit for something. For the specific problem I have on hand I know it will become unfeasible for real-world problem sizes (NP hard to be exact).

what NP hard, real-world problem size do you have feasible turing machines for

I am trying to (re)implement a SAT solver.
